# Bitnami AWS Apache L Flag Not Working on 301's followed by a Blanket Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, amazon-web-services

Im having some serrrrrrious, headache with the following apache config on bitnami stack running on Amazon AWS.

The following htaccess.conf for the domain is taking the last rewrite rule and ignoring the [L] flag. Also i can't use a rewrite condition as i have far too many exceptions to accommodate for.

Test on my Mac OS X Apache stack and was working but keeps dying on the live box with everything going to the last redirect. I have also tested variations with RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} but no avail.

Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine on

```
RewriteRule ^about/ http://www.example.co.uk/about/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/ http://www.example.co.uk/blog/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^cookie-policy/ http://www.example.co.uk/c [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^hello-world/ http://www.example.co.uk/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^landlords-insurance/ http://www.example.co.uk/l/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^liability-insurance/ http://www.example.co.uk/ml/ [R=301,NC,L]
#Followed by another 300 simmilar 301 rules (Condensed for Stack Overflow)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.co.uk/page/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is `www.example.co.uk` the same server as `www.example2.co.uk`?

Comment: Nope... hence the tricky part... i could give up and route the whole thing through index.php and make a PHP based redirect mapping, but really not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a slash at the beginning of the pattern, e.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^/about/ http://www.example.co.uk/about/ [R=301,NC,L]
...
```

**Edit**: Ok this is my last try. Try replacing the `L` flag with the `END` flag (it seems to make sense according to the description [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end), but this is just an educated guess).

Comment: Makes no difference... im seriously sitting here puzzled. The patterns all work once i have remove the RewriteRule ^(.*)$... Rule at the end.